# Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, syntax-error

I am not sure why is it giving this error. Braces seem to be right. Another thing is that the same program works in Windows-eclipse but not in eclipse for Mac. What could be the reason?

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Debug 
{
    private int something = 0;
    private Vector list = new Vector();

    public void firstMethod()
    {
        thirdMethod(something);
        something = something + 1;
    }
    public void secondMethod()
    {
        thirdMethod(something);
        something = something + 2;
    }
    public void thirdMethod(int value)
    {
        something = something + value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Debug debug = new Debug();
        debug.firstMethod();
        debug.secondMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Richa your code has only 29 lines

Comment: http://f.cl.ly/items/0i0533373b1E1i432I36/Error.tiff

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah, ok - it's probably a control-Z or other unprintable character at the end of the file that is ignored in Windows but not on the Mac.  You copied the source from Windows to the Mac.  Delete the last few characters and re-enter them - I think it will go away.  I don't do Mac, though - I'm just guessing.

Comment: You should also be able to convert the line delimiters (which I suspect is the actual problem) from the File menu.

Comment: @nitind, would line delimiter problems be reported as on the line past the last line in the file?  I would have expected to see them on line 1 or 2.  Does the same setting quietly cleans up other stuff too?

Comment: Possibly, it's hard to really speculate on where it would report an issue.  All that action does is convert line delimiters--anything it cleans up is only cleaned up because the line delimiters were changed.

Comment: I got this error when a backtick (`) got in my JSP. You can also use Notepad++ "Show All Characters" feature to see characters that aren't displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem importing my projects from mac to linux Slackware.
Mac OSX creates some temporary files with the same name of the files in folders (._filename) in all folders.
Usually these files are invisible in Mac OSX, but in the other OSs no.
Eclipse can find these files and tries to handle like sources (._filename.java).
I solved deleting these files.

Answer (score 1):

Only way i could resolve this problem was press Ctrl+A to select all text of file then Ctrl+C to copy them then delete file and create new class with intellij idea then Ctrl+P to paste text in new file. this resolve my problem and compiler never show error after do this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when we copy and paste .It happens when there may be some character which is unrecognized in one platform but recognized in other.

I would suggest don't copy rather try to write the entire code by yourself. It should work

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I imported a project I created in a Mac, to Windows. As @Massimo says Mac creates **._filename,java** files which eclipse running in windows consider as source files. This is what causes the problem.

They are hidden files, which you can see when you select the option, "Show hidden files and folders" under folder options in Windows machine. Deleting these files solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message trying to call a subjob from a tRunJob component.  In the tRunJob I had both checked "transmit whole context" AND listed individual parameters in the parameters/values box.  Once I removed the additional parameters it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably hidden characters in the line. If you move your cursor through the characters and your cursor doesn't move in one character, that means there is an invalid character in the line. Delete those and it should work. Also try copying and pasting the line to an hex editor and you will see the invalid characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem many times in eclipse . What i found is that select all code - cut it using Ctrl + x and then save the file and again paste the code using Ctrl + V . This works for me many times when i copy the code from another editor.

Comment: Any particular reasons why this seems to work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue while copying the code from one machine to another.

The issue was with Space only you need to identify the red mark in your eclipse code.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you copy the source to Notepad - save the file (as anything), ensuring ASCI encoding is selected - the character will be converted to a question-mark which you can then delete - then copy the code back to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse right click on the file -> Properties -> resources
In Text file encoding select US-ASCII

This way you will see all the special char, you can then find & replace
And then format the code

[image: Eclipse Option]