# having compiler error on Eclipse that is impossible to have

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently writing some code on Eclipse, but strangely, I got a compile error [image]

And this is the code I have

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("What is happening?");
    }
}
```

Then I thought might just be some wrong with my code, but:
[image]
Error:

```
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete InterfaceBody
- Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", interface 
     expected
```

Now I have no code, but it still says I did some wrong? So what happened? The file I have is not an interface. Nor I even have any characters, why did I get this error message?

BTW: when I have nothing written on another file, it works fine:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code; copy them into your post and format them appropriatly.

Comment: @tibetiroka my code is not even important, I just want to show that I'm getting this error even when I have nothing written...

Comment: An empty class is not valid for the compiler

Comment: Setup a fresh project and check if the error is still there.

Comment: @tibetiroka It worked on another file... QAQ

Comment: @tibetiroka I tried it out and my eclipse don't throw an error when the file is empty

Comment: I think he configured the main method to be in the Main.java file, which is not there if it is empty. About your comment: the compiler does not throw an error if the file is empty, but the .class file will not be created.

Comment: @Alex "Setup a fresh project and check if the error is still there. " how to do that? Do I just reopen my eclipse?

Comment: If you right-click `Main.java` and select `Properties`, what is the value of `Size:`? I bet it is not "0  bytes".

Comment: @Andreas I sorry, but it is 0 bytes

Comment: If you use mac this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129371/syntax-error-on-token-invalid-character-delete-this-token

Comment: @tibetiroka but I don't even have anything... T_T

Comment: @lierwu The problem is in your main.java, not in the empty file (if I understood that correctly)

Comment: So both `Main.java` and `New.java` says "0 bytes"? Then try to clean the project: Select the `Project` pull-down menu, select `Clean...`, check `Clean all projects`, click the `Clean` button. --- If that fixes it, make sure `Project` > `Build Automatically` is has a checkmark next to it.

Comment: @tibetiroka, yes, but the answer, it said: "You copied the source from Windows to the Mac." I don't even have anything...

Comment: @Andreas wow, thank you, it worked!

Comment: Then create a self-answer, explain how you fixed the problem, so others with same issue might find it. Then accept the self-answer. Might even give you the [`Self-Learner`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the eclipse said zero bytes, then go to the project
[image]

Click Clean and check the box said: "Clean all projects"
[image]
Hit clean, and that would solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem before and it was caused by the characters inserted by my input type language when it is not English. So please make sure your input type language is English when you use Eclipse.

Comment: All of them were English and it did not even work on an empty file. But anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you have a non-printable character in your source file, which the Java compiler then rejects.

If you open Terminal, and look at the file with `xxd` (a hex viewer) you can see the file's contents in hex and look out for odd characters. `0a` is a newline, possibly `0d` as well, and space is `20` with text in the `40-50` range and `60-70` range for upper and lower cases.

Most likely you've got a non-breaking space or a BOM byte identifier in the file somewhere which is causing the problem.

It could also be the case that Eclipse thinks the file's content type is something else (e.g. EBCDIC) and thus it looks odd -- you can check what the file encoding is (usually defaults to UTF-8) with Edit - Set Encoding. There's also a 'Show whitespace characters' in Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors, which can sometimes show where the problem lies.